# ERROR: Quantum ESPRESSO compiling under Intel oneAPI

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso

I tried to compile Quantum ESPRESSO using the Intel compilers and the MKL libraries. But it went sideways with an error as follows,

[image: Compiling Error]

What I did was as follows,

1. Started with a fresh Ubuntu distro in windows 10 wsl
2. Download and install the Intel oneAPI Base and HCP toolkits
3. source the setvars.sh script by Intel to set the environment variables
4. Extract the Quantum ESPRESSO source code
5. Custom configure QE by executing the configure file (./configure MPIF90=mpiifort CC=mpiicc F90=ifort F77=mpiifort -enable-parallel)
6. Edit the make.inc by setting the "BLAS_LIBS=", "LAPACK_LIBS=", "SCALAPACK_LIBS=", and "FFT_LIBS=" to "-L${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64 -lmkl_scalapack_lp64 -lmkl_intel_lp64 -lmkl_sequential -lmkl_core -lmkl_blacs_intelmpi_lp64 -lpthread -lm -ldl" as given by Intel link line advisor.
7. Edit the make.inc by setting the "MPI_LIBS=" to "-L/opt/intel/oneapi/mpi/2021.7.1/lib -lmpi"
8. Compiling QE by make pw

I can't figure out the problem here and would appreciate the view from an expert on the matter.

Thank you, Best Regards.

Chamara

Comment: Can you please post the full output in a text format (use pastebin or something similar)? From what I can see, the compiler is expecting a module file named "m_common_io.mod" which should have been compiled before. But it is not present, so the build fails. Either there is an issue with the build system setting include paths, or in the order of compile or the module compilation failed.

Comment: Thank for your comment Maiti. You're right, compiler fails to open the m_common_io.mod due to the lack of m4 utility. After installing m4, compilation went smoothly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To compile QE v.7.1 it requires m4 utility [1]. After installing m4, it went smoothly.

[1] - https://gitlab.com/QEF/q-e/-/wikis/home

Chamara

Comment: I am curious if you had any issues after your build? Did the run tests all work? I am trying to do a similar build in WSL that I can share with students at my university. I've successfully built 7.2 on my RHEL 7 Linux box with Intel 2019 compilers. I am trying to use the oneapi compilers in a WSL distribution and while the build is successful (i.e. all binaries built) many run tests fail. What WSL distro and oneapi version are you using?

Comment: @SeanRommel you might want to post this as a separate question. The author of this answer hasn't been online for a month.

Comment: @SeanRommel Yeah, I did encounter the same issue, but the executables worked fine and I could run my own input scripts without a problem. Therefore I didn't bother about it. However, did you follow the steps in here https://gitlab.com/QEF/q-e/-/issues/15 ?